# Empirical rule(68 - 95 - 99.7) in higher dimensions

Tags: normal-distribution

I would like to know if there's an equivalent of the [Empirical Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule) for higher dimensions. More specifically, I am interested in the $99\%$ part. To explain it in more details, from a practical viewpoint if you give me a univariate normal distribution $N(\mu, \sigma)$ I will work in $[\mu - 3\sigma, \mu+3\sigma]$ instead of $[-\infty, \infty]$ and that's ok. Now, given a multivariariate normal, it is possible to find an interval for every dimension so that $\approx 99\%$ lies in $[a_1,b_1]\times[a_2,b_2]\times...\times[a_d,b_d]$?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's more convenient to do things in terms of ellipsoidal sets

$$E_\alpha = \left\{x\in\mathbb{R}^p\,|\,\left(x-\mu\right)^\top \Sigma^{-1} \left(x-\mu\right) \leq \chi^2_{p,1-\alpha}\right\},$$

using the $1-\alpha$-quantile of the chi-squared distribution with $p$ degrees of freedom. (Above, $\Sigma$ is the covariance matrix.) The reason is because uncertainty is "traded" between different dimensions in a way that intervals don't really describe. Like, if you consider two dimensions, and construct the usual $\left(1-\alpha\right)$-level confidence region in each one, the coverage of these two intervals will be more conservative than $1-\alpha$. Furthermore, you can shrink one interval and expand the other while maintaining the same level of coverage. This is basically what the ellipsoid does -- if you are closer to the boundary of the $\left(1-\alpha\right)$ confidence set in one dimension, you must be closer to the center in the other dimensions.

Comment: Let's see if I got it. For example in 2 dimensions, I could take a very large $x$ and $y$ just over $99\%$ or I could do it the other way around. And I could also take values in between. So we can see the trade as starting with a very wide parallelogram and pushing from the sides so it becomes narrow but very tall. Right? If I am, I would like to go one step further. I choose intervals from my work because I can easily divide them into smaller ones, eg split the $[\mu-3\sigma,\mu+3\sigma]$ in N parts and see how many samples fall into every subinterval. Can I do the same with ellipsoids?

Comment: A parallelogram doesn't reflect the symmetry of the normal density. Basically, the idea is that, if your $x$ coordinate is out in the 99\% range, then your $y$ coordinate should be close to the center, because the confidence level is calculated jointly for the entire vector. An ellipsoid allows you to make this tradeoff smoothly. If the two dimensions are i.i.d., then any point on the sphere centered around the mean has the same confidence level. This is not true for the box.

Comment: I agree about the symmetry. I was talking about how the trade is not good with parallelograms because you have many options. I guess it wasn't clear. What about the divide part?

Comment: Ah, sorry, must have misread you. Maybe you can consider dividing it into subellipsoids (like concentric circles) by varying the \alpha value?

Comment: How can I do that? Intuitively, if I draw smaller ellipsoids inside a big one I will never fully cover it.

Comment: Couldn't you look at the points in between two consecutive ellipsoids, like $a < x^\top \Sigma^{-1} x < b$, with the outermost ellipsoid being the "final" one?

Comment: So the values around the mean will be in an ellipsoid and the rest will be in the space that is the difference of two ellipsoids?(an ellipsoid disc sort of)

Comment: Yes. You could have multiple concentric ellipsoids if you want a finer partition.

Comment: Thanks for both your answer and the discussion in the comments. It's not exactly what I asked for but if I can make it work I will accept your answer.